# Why is the transistor in this dimming circuit getting very hot?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, comparator, dimming

[image]

This is a fairly simple dimming circuit using a dual opamp (IC1) as a comparator to control the brightening and dimming of a light bulb.

- The switch (pin 2 IC1a) is a contact connection to ground.
- Trimpot 3 controls the speed of the brightening when the switch is connected to ground.
- Trimpot 2 controls the speed of dimming.

The issue is that when using a 10 W bulb, [transistor](https://uk.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MJB44H11_D-2315689.pdf) (Q1) gets warm during the brightening/dimming time. The longer the times are (based on TM2/TM3), the warmer it gets. It gets very hot when testing with a 25 W bulb.

Even if the trimmers are set to 0 ohms (thus only R5, R6 resistance) and there is virtually no brightening/dimming happening, the transistor gets extremely hot almost immediately.

Should there be a current limiting resistor from the transistor's emitter to ground?

What else could allow the transistor to function cooler?

Is it even possible to operate a D2PAK form factor that is meant to switch up to 40 W (3.3 A) without a heatsink and only PCB heatsinking?

Comment: What value is C2? Also, Q1 is labeled as MJB44H11T4G, which is an NPN BJT. But your symbol is an IGBT; please clarify which is correct.

Comment: @marcelm MJB44H11T4G, but I have also tested with MJD3055RLG. But as another comment has mentioned, it seems that I should be using a MOSFET, not BJT.

Comment: Right, but the symbol in your schematic is for an IGBT, which neither of those transistors are. This can confuse people who are trying to help you. Please use the correct symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got at least a couple of problems.  One is that you've greatly changed the circuit from the one you were following.  The example uses one LM358 op-amp as an oscillator and a second op-amp as a comparator to drive a MOSFET with a pulse width modulated signal.

The modifications you've made appear to have changed the circuit from PWM to a linear regulator.  In that case, even the MOSFET would get warm or hot.

The second problem is that you are using a NPN bipolar junction transistor instead of the specified N-channel MOSFET.

The [NJVMJB44H11](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mjb44h11-d.pdf) has a collector to emitter saturation voltage of 1V.  At 1A of current, that'd be at least 1W of power dissipated in the transistor.  That's a lot more than the the 200mW mentioned on the web site you referred to.

MOSFETs have a certain minimum resistance when fully on (conducting.)  That can be very low, resulting in low switching losses.

BJTs have a certain minimum collector to emitter voltage when fully switched on.  The product of the voltage from collector to emitter and the current through the collector tells you how much power the transistor itself will waste as heat.

Saturation in the NJVMJB44H11 is rated at a base current of 0.4A.  Your LM358 can't deliver the current needed to push the transistor into saturation, so you will have a higher voltage drop across the transistor and therefore more power loss - the transistor will get hotter.

Comment: This makes sense. The BUZ10 is NLA and I had a hard time trying to find a similar transistor and in SMD. Is there one you could recommend? Or which MOSFET specifications should I be searching for?

Comment: You need to look at the drain-source on resistance (\$R_{DSon}\$,) the threshold voltage, the current ratings, and the voltage ratings.

Comment: I found one with Drain−to−Source On Resistance 4.8 mOhm, Gate Threshold Voltage 2.0-4.0 V, Drain−to−Source Voltage 40 V, Continuous Drain Current 59 A. The problem I see here is that my gate voltage is around 6 V.

Comment: How does that compare to the BUZ10?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do whit the BJT. The concept is totally different.

Comment: Drain−to−Source Voltage is 10 V lower than BUZ10, but BUZ10's Static Drain-source On Resistance os only 0.06 Ohm, Continuous Drain Current is lower on the BUZ10 at 23 A. So I'm guessing that the  would be a problem.

Comment: @Louis Well actually, using a BJT is still an issue, just a different one from not using PWM. Without PWM, the transistor will have to dissipate up to 10W or so. With PWM using a BJT, it might be 1W, but which is still way more than what a MOSFET could achieve.

Comment: @TooTea So scrap this circuit and do something along the lines of https://www.electroschematics.com/car-interior-light-dimmer/ ?

Comment: @TooTea Agree, but the problem was stated during brightening/dimming, when the transistor is NOT saturated since no PWN is used.

Answer (score 5):

It's getting hot because your dimming circuit has to absorb the power so it doesn't go to your device. The lower the voltage to your bulb, the greater the voltage drop across your transistor.  There are other ways, hence the popularity of switch-mode power supplies (smps).

Comment: Quote from a similar circuit online: "At a current of 2 A the voltage drop across the transistor is about 100 mV, giving rise to a dissipation of 200 mW. This is such a small amount that no heatsink is required."

Comment: @Fid:  Take a closer look at that "200mW dissipation" circuit.  You'll almost certainly find that it is using pulse width modulation (rapidly switching the light on and off to dim it) rather than using the transistor as a big variable resistor like your circuit does.

Comment: @JRE https://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/luxury-car-interior-light.html It isn't used as a resistor per se, rather PWM.

Comment: @Fid But the circuit shown in your question doesn't do any PWM at all. Please post a complete and accurate diagram of your actual circuit.

Comment: @TooTea Quote from the article: "The dimming of the light is implemented by means of pulse-width modulation. This requires a triangle wave oscillator and a comparator." I know this isn't PWM in the microcontroller sense, but by the definition of PWM, even quickly turning a switch on and off is a very crude form of PWM. (PWM is a method of reducing the average power delivered by an electrical signal, by effectively chopping it up into discrete parts. The average value of voltage (and current) fed to the load is controlled by turning the switch between supply and load on and off at a fast rate.)

Comment: @Fid I do know what PWM means, thank you very much. The circuit in the article is based on PWM. The _completely different_ circuit shown in your question is linear.

Comment: Your circuit does not have a triangle wave oscillator, unless that's outside the screenshot. If you do have an oscillator, show it.

Answer (score 3):

> *(Q1) gets warm during the brightening/dimming time.*

It warms during the brightening and dimming phases because the [transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mjb44h11-d.pdf) is forced into its linear region and, because of this, it drops voltage from collector to emitter. Therefore it starts to dissipate power and heat due to the current flow AND that voltage drop.

> *Should there be a current limiting resistor from the transistor's
> emitter to ground?*

That would also limit the full power of the bulb.

> *Even if the trimmers are set to 0 ohms (thus only R5, R6 resistance)
> and there is virtually no brightening/dimming happening, the
> transistor gets extremely hot almost immediately.*

The current gain of the BJT is a minimum of 60 therefore, if the load requires 2 amps, you need to push at least 33 mA into the base. That current has to flow through the 470 Ω resistor (R7) and would drop 16 volts across it but, it's unlikely you'd be able to muster 33 mA from the [LM358 op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) without the output voltage dropping considerably hence, I suspect your design is flawed in this respect. Of course, 33 mA is only just enough to partially turn the BJT on; in reality, you'd be looking for at least 100 mA into the base.

Seems to me that a MOSFET would be a better option here.

> *What else could allow the transistor to function cooler?*

I'd consider using PWM to control dimming (a digital method).

Comment: It already is based on a method of PWM. Please see https://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/luxury-car-interior-light.html

Comment: @Fid I don't see how the circuit in your link is relevant; you built a different circuit. Your circuit does not appear to employ PWM.

Comment: @Fid your original signal (on the left of what you show in your diagram) may be a PWM based signal but, you are using standard analogue circuits to turn that PWM signal into an analogue signal so no, fundamentally, your circuit does not use PWM to drive the transistor.

Comment: So could recreating the linked circuit be a solution? I know my circuit is slightly rearranged, but I had the notion that the theory of operation is virtually the same.

Comment: @Fid The circuit in the link uses PWM, the circuits you propose is linear. This is a totally different approach. Look at my answer for explanation.

Comment: @Fid It doesn't seem to be "slightly rearranged", not even heavily rearranged, but actually completely different. In the original, IC1A is an oscillator and IC1B a comparator. In the diagram in your question, IC1A does who-knows-what and IC1B is a unity-gain buffer.

Answer (score 1):

When the light bulb is brightening/dimming, the voltage is divided between the light bulb and the transistor. For a 10W bulb at 12 volts, the light bulb resistance, when hot, would be 14.4 ohm.

During dimming, at mid point the light bulb and transistor will both dissipate equal power, about 2.5W each. When an incandescent bulb is "cold", the resistance is much lower and the power dissipated during dimming at mid point could be as high as 25W. The transition will result in heating the transistor.

PWM is a must for such application or the use of a very big heatsink.

For LED bulbs, since they are non-linear, this approach wouldn't work either.